# Access values from model manager

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to simplify a view with a manager but cannot access the values that I return in said manager, can someone help me understand how this works ? Many thanks

Manager

```
class CategoryManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_cat_name(self, category):
        categories  =  Category.objects.all()
        if self.filter(name=category).exists():
            instance =  self.filter(name=category)
            if instance :
                return instance, categories
            else :
                raise Http404("Category does not exists")
```

View :

```
def category_view(request, category):
    qs = Category.objects.get_by_cat_name(category)
    context = {'qs': qs   #would like to use "instance" and "categories" in context }
    return render(request, 'store/category.html',context)
```

Model :

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    objects =  CategoryManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: `instance, categories = Category.objects.get_by_cat_name(category)` does this work?

Comment: It does, thanks a lot Sid